# Code Blocks - empty console

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I'm running any project in Code Blocks I see this:

[image]

[image]

or
What should i do?

Comment: Try disabling the antivirus of your system and run again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question and for using CodeBlocks as IDE.

The error message you are getting is because codeBlocks has no 'write' privileges to the folder where it wants to place the binary (or executable).  You need to change the privileges of the folder where you ave your projects stored to Read/Write/Execute for all.

If you need to know how to do that, you need to put the specs of your system in the comments, I will tell you here on how to.

KR

Hewi

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this message when you try to recompile an executable that is already running.

If you got this error, you should simply close your application. If you can't see an application window and you're still getting the error, open *Task manager* (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), find your program in `processes` list and close it from here.